# Trying to count how many certain types of award a dog has in results table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a dog show results website. I am trying to count and show how many certain types of award a dog has. 
There are two tables. 
Table 1
Result table - with ResultID, dog_id and Award (for example I am trying to find out how many strings that match 'DCC' in award column).
Table 2 
Dog table - with dog_id.

I have tried an inner join but it counts is not working correctly. For example, the count should show 1 as I know a certain dog has only 1 'DCC' but it shows 2505 not sure where it's getting this figure from?

```
<?php
 $query = "SELECT result.resultID, result.dog_id, result.award, COUNT(*) AS dcc
        FROM result INNER JOIN dogs
        ON result.dog_id = dogs.dog_id
        GROUP BY result.dog_id, result.award
        ORDER BY dcc";

        $select_all_dcc = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $dcc_counts = mysqli_num_rows ($select_all_dcc);
        echo    "<strong class='amount'>{$dcc_counts}</strong>"
```

Comment: please try with `SELECT result.dog_id, result.award, COUNT(*) AS dcc FROM result INNER JOIN dogs ON result.dog_id = dogs.dog_id GROUP BY result.dog_id, result.award ORDER BY dcc` because result.resultID is not an aggregated field.

Comment: Sorry didn't really change anything, thanks though for input appreciated

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` doesn't give you results from the query. Don't use it. Fetch the actual result instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with this code

```
if (isset($_GET['dog_id'])) {
$query = "SELECT result.* , dogs.dog_name, shows.show_title, shows.show_id
FROM  `result` 
INNER JOIN  `dogs` ON result.dog_id = dogs.dog_id
INNER JOIN  `shows` ON result.show_id = shows.show_id
AND result.dog_id = " . $_GET['dog_id'] . " 
WHERE award = 'DCC' OR award = 'BCC'";

$select_all_dcc = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$dcc_counts = mysqli_num_rows ($select_all_dcc);
echo    "<strong class='amount'>{$dcc_counts}</strong>";
                                            }
```

Comment: Please do not use concatenation for adding parameters to a query. Use prepared statements.